# bugs in programs and fighting with them

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am relatively new to programming and especially  to Java... So it takes me quite a long time to look for small snags - for example today I spent 5 hours to find that I wrote "servlet-name" as "sevlet-name" in DD and later on 2 more hours because I did not know that ServletExtractListener subclass should be public - Tomcat did not want to start.

Does it always take so long to debug programs or is it just my lack of talent in Computer science? Which tools do you use to find those small snags fast except brain? =)

Comment: voting to move to programmers.stackexchange.com as I think this is more of a general question for the programming community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The malformed `web.xml` should have thrown an error in the server logs--the logs are one of your best friends, so it's good to familiarize yourself with them early.

Being able to decipher stack traces is a critical skill; quite often devs don't look far enough down the trace (following the "caused by" chain) and miss important clues.

Classes that anything else accesses should essentially always be public.

It's a lot about experience, patience, a critical eye for detail, more patience, more experience, and more patience.

It's a process.

There *are* tools that can help, like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), etc. but they won't find logic errors (usually) or anything outside of Java code (like XML config files). But most config file errors will be caught by a framework or container, since they generally follow an XSD or DTD.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse debugger is where I spend 99% of my time when debugging a program. Just make sure you know what is exactly happening at each step and follow variables. It comes with practice I would say.

Answer (score 1):

As you spend more time programming you'll get a better grasp of what the error messages you get from your compilers and supporting environments *mean*. Writing good error messages is *extremely* difficult (especially because the errors are inevitably because the input is malformed or wrong in some way -- trying to figure out in what ways it might be wrong is difficult too) -- so you'll just have to get enough practice to know what to look for with different warnings and errors.

Oh yes, *do* make sure you're using the full amount of warnings your compiler can give you. It's eerie how well the compiler can do crystal-ball work sometimes.